# Image frames not displayed correctly with ros image_view [ubuntu 14]

Tags: image, camera, ros

The camera I am using is a Point Grey Chameleon 3 model `CM3-U3-13Y3M-CS`. I am running it via ROS indigo with these commands:

`$ roslaunch flea3 single_node.launch device:=15508342`

`$ rosrun image_view image_view image:=/pg_15508342/image_raw`

However, quite often I get a strange image like this:
[image]
What could be the cause of this and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you checked if the images look the same when displayed with other nodes? You can use rviz for example.

Comment: I checked usign windows and it worked fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "using windows"? I guess you are accessing the camera with some other program that is not related to ROS? What I would like to know is, if the problem is really with `image_view` or with the node that publishes the images. To check this, it is important to really look at the images that are published on the topic `/pg_15508342/image_raw` but display them with a node other than `image_view`.

Comment: @luator By Windows, I mean that I used the driver provided by Point Grey on a Windows machine (without ros). It worked perfectly.  I will update you about the rest  as soon as I get something (am reinstalling ubuntu...)

Comment: @luator I tried with `rqt_image_view` and got the same issue (sporadically). With `rviz` the image remained black... Do not know why (?) Also, I recorded the sequence as a bag file. Then closed everything, replayed the bag file, and viewed the images again with rqt... but the same issue again. Note that only after a certain time I get this issue. I checked my usb port with `lsusb` and it is indeed usb 3 compatible though its color is black (not the supposed blue color).... My text try will be to grab the images with another cpp node and display the images at lower frquency using opencv...